# Bind Razor TextArea to Model class attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC app and one of the controllers lead with CRUD of class model (class A).
This class model have an attribute that is a list of others objects (object B) Each one of this objects only have a string name property.

I need to show the View with a textArea (and i do it this with success) and after user submits, I want to split the textarea input by comma, create objects of type B for each value and insert the results in the list attribute.

My point is I do not know how to do that. Can i get the user input in controller?

My textArea:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.List, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways of doing this with nicer UI (this might get you started:  [Passing the collection of selected values from a Select2-Multi DropDownList to a Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025651/passing-the-collection-of-selected-values-from-a-select2-multi-dropdownlist-to-a))

But to answer your exact question:  Use a string property in your ViewModel to "wrap" the List property.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
    public string MyListAsString
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(",", MyList);
        }
        set
        {
            MyList = value.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

In your razor view, don't use MyList anywhere -- use MyListAsString, which will get and set MyList when the ModelBinder does its things.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.MyListAsString,
                  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

(Best practises:  I have renamed your List property to MyList, so as not to reuse an existing identifier.  And you probably don't want to use "control-label" class on something that isn't a label.  Try "form-control")